# Two decidable languages for which a mapping reducibility does not exist?

Tags: computer-science

The trivial null language might not be reduced to another language, but are there standard examples of two decidable languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ such that there is no mapping reduction possible from $L_1$ to $L_2$ or vice versa?